# How to activate PyMongo Intellisense in Visual Code?

Tags: python, mongodb, visual-studio-code, pymongo

I'm learning how to use Python and MongoDB with VisualCode and I was wondering how I can get the Intellisense to work with the PyMongo package? I'd like it if I was able to see what functions I would be able to use with the MongoClient.

Is this something I need to install or is this something that isn't supported?

Comment: See [Python in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python) and possibly other marketplace offerings with similar functionality. There is nothing "pymongo specific" about this, as the "intellisense" is just going to inspect packages in use. Also there is [Documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/) for which knowledge of what the things do is far better for you than just being prompted with a list of available class functions. Reading documentation is really how you learn.

Comment: There is one pymongo specific thing :) The standard way how to work with pymongo API is `db.nameOfTheCollection.find(query)`. Maybe code completion (Intellisense in this case) can have trouble with understanding what that means, because of course the `db` object has no direct attribute `nameOfTheCollection` (it's all dynamic via `__getattr__`).

Comment: Also I believe Visual Studio (at least with C# and MS SQL) can be configured with code completion even for database schema (table names, columns names and types...), but possibly not easily for Python and pymongo/MongoDB.

Comment: @Messa your comment can be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

With `pymongo` we typically use the database and the collection in this way:

```
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.testDb
collection = db.users
```

As @Messa mentioned, the intellisense have trouble with dynamic attributes like this, if you want to active the intellisense, you should use the indexers of `MongoClient` to access the database and the collection

```
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client["testDb"]
collection = db["users"]
```